# Use Aggregate function in C# Linq to retrieve data from CRM

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, dynamics-crm

Here I am trying to evaluate max date (latest date) condition and for that I think I could use MAX() function.

From syntax perspective I am not able to find correct way. Here below is my query.

```
var sfcStatusQuery = (from Carrier in _orgContext.CreateQuery("account")
                                          join SafetyFitnessCert in _orgContext.CreateQuery("mot_safetyfitnesscertificate")
                                            on Carrier["accountid"] equals SafetyFitnessCert["mot_carriernumber"]
                                          where (SafetyFitnessCert["mot_expirydate"] == null && (int)SafetyFitnessCert["statecode"] == 0)
                                          where SafetyFitnessCert.FormattedValues["new_sfcstatusname"].ToString().Equals("Suspended")
                                          where ((int)Carrier["statecode"] == 0 && Carrier["mot_number"].Equals(carrierNumber))
                                          //where SafetyFitnessCert["mot_lastreviseddate"]
                                          select new
                                          {
                                              SafetyCertSuspFlag = "Y"
                                          }).FirstOrDefault();
```

In above query the commented where condition which I try to correct by using aggregate function MAX. As this query may/may not contain more than one record with "Suspended" status for a particular carrier number.

Please advise.

Comment: I don't think the max function is the best way to get the latest date unless that is all you care about, and none of the other data?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want record with that date to be latest. In this case I would just sort the data by that date descending. If you do so the latest date will be in the first record than you do `FirstOrDefault()` and your done.

so instead of `where` use `order by SafetyFitnessCert["mot_lastreviseddate"] descending`